# Create Stripe Customer in Swift

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, stripe-payments

I am working on integrating Stripe into my Swift App. On reading the documentation Stripe recommends that you create a new customer when you sign up the user to your app (I am using Parse-Server). And says your user doesn't need to enter credit card information at this time.

> We strongly recommend you create this Customer at the same time you create your user on your own backend, so that every user is guaranteed to have an associated Customer (this is fine even if you don't collect your user's payment information when they sign up—it's totally OK to have a Customer without any attached cards).

I have setup an express server to handle the request and create the user. However on Stripes API Reference (https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_customer) it implies that you need a token to create a user.

How do I create a customer on their backend if the user hasn't entered a credit card, thus a token isn't generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. This works just fine. You just need to send in the email address as the only parameter.

```
  stripe.customers.create({ 
   email: req.body.email },
    function(err, customer) {
     err; // null if no error occurred
     customer; // the created customer object
   }
 );
```

Comment: whats the class of `stripe` here?